# SCCM Deploy Application without Detection Method

Tags: sccm

I am trying to install an MSI and it is failing the detection method. Is there a way I can install this MSI thru SCCM without a detection method?

The script is very simple to install the MSI is basic:
msiexec /i "\jbocleit\SoftwareInstalls\Worksmart\FrontEnd.msi" /q

I tried to just create a script and run that and that did not do anything. Any thoughts would be great.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no way to do an application without a detection method since that's what triggers an installation.

What are you using for you detection method?  If you are using the standard Windows Installer detection make sure you have the proper GUID information

If you REALLY don't want to use a detection method than create a Package instead.  You can make it show up in Software Center if you want and in the deployment you can set the set package to only rerun if the installation failed (based on the exit code).

Comment: Packages are still a perfectly valid form of deployment (and I know quite some reasons why it's the preferable one). No need to make it sound like some last resort option imo

Comment: Syberdoor, No need to get upset or offended about my post, I totally agree.  There are plenty of packages in my environment and they serve their purpose.  For this question, the original post describes using a cut and dry MSI install so for that functionality Application is the preferred method and packages should be the backup.

Answer (score 0):

If your MSI deployment is failing on the detection method then I strongly suspect something else is at play. Can you confirm the GUID of the MSI is the same in the Registry and in the MSI Property table?

As Paul G has already mentioned, you could use a package instead if you 'just want it installed'. But since it's an MSI and this functionality is inbuilt into SCCM to handl MSIs, personally, I would resolve the issue.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

MSI thru SCCM without a detection method?

Deployments without detection method are not possible. But we can make the installation successful, even if the detection failed, by adding the 0x87D00324 code as a success return code to deployment, as in the picture below.

[image: click here to view where to add return code]